# RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running

Tags: python, веб-программирование, python-2.x, асинхронность, tornado

```
@gen.coroutine
def _get(self, account, data_id):
    "method implements getting data from db"
    query = "SELECT data FROM configuration WHERE name = '{0}' ;".format(account)
    cursor = yield self.db.execute(query)
    all_user_configuration = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(all_user_configuration) > 0:
        self.logger(LOG_NOTICE, 'data from db {0}'.format(all_user_configuration[0][0]))
        all_user_configuration = all_user_configuration[0][0]
    else:
        raise gen.Return(None)
    if all_user_configuration.get(self.key_word, None) is None:
        raise gen.Return(None)
    elif data_id == '':
        self.logger(LOG_NOTICE,'before super unknow thing'+ str(all_user_configuration[self.key_word]))
        raise gen.Return(all_user_configuration[self.key_word])
    else:
        for app in all_user_configuration[self.key_word]:
            if app.get('id', None) == data_id:
                raise gen.Return(app)
        else:
            raise gen.Return(None)
```

используется tornado 
Функция обработчик запроса

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self, account, data_id):
  .................
  IOLoop.current().run_sync(_get)
  all_user_configudation = IOLoop.current().run_sync(_get)`
```

Возникает ошибка RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running в IOLoop.current().run_sync(_get) 
А причина не понятна(

Comment: Обработчик `post` уже выполняет в цикле, а `run_sync` пытается запустить второй.

Comment: А есть возможность синхронно выполнить асинхронную функцию?

Comment: Нет, все вызовы в цепочке должны быть асинхронными.

Comment: Спасибо, а если у меня версия python 2.6, чтобы вернуть значения из ассинхронной функции я могу использовать только raise gen.Return? или есть более правильное решение?